# better way of handling conditional check in interpolated string angular 4

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement a conditional check within the interpollated expression in angular4.   I have written the logic which works fine but would want to check if there is a better way of doing it. My concern is that I am having 20 such fields in my form. Do I need to explicty check the condition > 1000000 in every line or is

My Code

```
  <div class="tb-row d-flex flex-row">
                    <div class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-6">{{'CAPTIVES.RESULTS.NVA.PREMIUM_PAID'|translate}}</div>
                      <div *ngFor="let result of results" class="tb-cell col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 col-6"> {{(result?.captiveInsPremiumPaidTotal > 1000000) ? (result?.captiveInsPremiumPaidTotal|number:'.0-2') : (result?.captiveInsPremiumPaidTotal|number:'.0-0') }} </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: you could add method in you components and just call the method in html. For better readability

Answer (score 0):

This is a little bit cleaner:

```
<div *ngFor="let result of results">
  <ng-container *ngIf="result.captiveInsPremiumPaidTotal">
    {{ captiveInsPremiumPaidTotal > 1000000 ? captiveInsPremiumPaidTotal | number:'.0-2' :  captiveInsPremiumPaidTotal | number:'.0-0')
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

You can also consider creating your own number formatting pipe, which would be a wrapper around the built in `Decimal` pipe.

The custom formatter pipe could look like this:

```
import { Component, Pipe } from '@angular/core';
import {DecimalPipe} from '@angular/common';

@Pipe({
  name: 'customFormatter'
})
export class CustomFormatterPipe {
  transform(val: string, ...args: any[]) {
    const format = args[0] ? '1.0-2' : '1.0-0'; 
    return this.decimalPipe.transform(val, format);
  }

  constructor(private decimalPipe: DecimalPipe) { }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template:`
    <div> {{ num | customFormatter: num > 100 }}</div>
  `,
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {  
  num = 1000;
}
```

As you can see it only selects one formatting (`'1.0-2' or '1.0-0'`) based on the boolean condition passed as an argument.

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tttp2e)